# How to mouse over on link in selinium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to mouse over of Investor link in [spicejet](http://www.spicejet.com/) page, which is under menu. 
[image: picture_of_menu]

This is the code that I'm using:

```
Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[4]/a"));
Actions mouseoveracActions=(Actions)
builder.moveToElement(element).build();
```

But I'm getting the exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure that the xpath is correct? Can you click the element? Does the problem only occur when you try to mouse over? What task are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The Xpath which one i taken that one is correct,no i am unable to click the element,when i am running the script that time it open the specified browser only,exception will occures while mouseover action is calling

Comment: How do you know that the Xpath is correct if you are unable to click the element?

Comment: I taken that Xpath by Using Firebug,I also tryed by takeing link also

Comment: Have you tried clicking the link by just finding the text on the page?

Comment: no,please give me suggestion how i will overcome to this problem,can i use SeleniumIDE to find xpath

Comment: I was suggesting what the guy below just answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with the code written below. Worked fine for me:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.spicejet.com/");
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Investors')]"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();
```